# webjobs working in local but not on app service environemnt

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

We have created a webapp in .net 6 using spa architecture. it is built using react and .net6. this is hosted in azure as app service.Our app service is working fine in local and published. We have a webjob built using C#(.net6) on top of same solution. But our webjob working in local but not working Azure app service environment when published.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Job triggered in main");

            var builder = new HostBuilder()
          .UseEnvironment("Development")
          .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, config) =>
          {
              config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
          })
          .ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
                b.AddExecutionContextBinding();
                b.AddTimers();
            });

            builder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
                var settings = new Settings(hostContext.Configuration);
                DIConfiguration.Configure(settings, services);

            });
            var host = builder.Build();
            using (host)
            {
                host.Start();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error message : {ex.Message} .stacktrace : {ex.StackTrace}");
        }

    }
```

Getting below error,

[02/25/2022 08:43:26 > 41d309: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[02/25/2022 08:43:27 > 41d309: SYS INFO] Run script 'EmailNotificationService.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[02/25/2022 08:43:27 > 41d309: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[02/25/2022 08:43:29 > 41d309: INFO] Job triggered in main
[02/25/2022 08:43:53 > 41d309: INFO] Error message : The listener for function 'Functions.ProcessQueueMessage' was unable to start. .stacktrace :    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.RecoverableException.TryRecover(ILogger logger) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Exceptions\RecoverableException.cs:line 81
[02/25/2022 08:43:53 > 41d309: INFO]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean allowRetry) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\FunctionListener.cs:line 79
[02/25/2022 08:43:53 > 41d309: INFO]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\FunctionListener.cs:line 61
[02/25/2022 08:43:53 > 41d309: INFO]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.CompositeListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\CompositeListener.cs:line 39
[02/25/2022 08:43:53 > 41d309: INFO]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.ListenerFactoryListener.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\ListenerFactoryListener.cs:line 47
[02/25/2022 08:43:53 > 41d309: INFO]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.ShutdownListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\ShutdownListener.cs:line 29
[02/25/2022 08:43:53 > 41d309: INFO]    at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\JobHost.cs:line 97
[02/25/2022 08:43:53 > 41d309: INFO]    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
[02/25/2022 08:43:53 > 41d309: INFO]    at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Start(IHost host)
[02/25/2022 08:43:53 > 41d309: INFO]    at NotificationService.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\a\1\s\EmailNotificationService\Program.cs:line 39
[02/25/2022 08:43:53 > 41d309: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success

Answer (score 0):

This might be relatable to an issue known as a "double-hop" issue:

- Your user connects to the Web app and authenticates as himself (using the Windows NTLM protocol, which needs the client to *know* her/his password).
- Impersonation is used in the Web app. It signifies that the code is executed using the user's identity.
- The call to SharePoint with your 'context.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials' tries to authenticate using the user's identity via NTLM. However, this needs the Web app *know* the user's password, which it does not. As a result, authentication fails (unless the client browses the Web app from the Web app server, in which case it works fine).

The simplest option is to stop impersonation at the Web app level (in web.config); all SharePoint requests will then be made using the application pool's identity (that will require permissions under SharePoint, of course).

Comment: I am not using any sharepoint in my webjob. This is simple webjob which looks into our db and sends some emails